# Is it possible to create a space character without using space? What is the character for this hexidecimal: 342 200 211

Tags: bash, character, ascii, space

I came across an unusual space character the other day:

```
[user@server] ~ $ echo AB583 923 | od -c
0000000   A   B   5   8   3 342 200 211   9   2   3  \n
0000014

[user@server] ~ $ echo AB583 923 | od -c
0000000   A   B   5   8   3       9   2   3  \n
0000012
```

I tried to decipher it with the hexidecimal representation command, but I don't understand enough about base level data to understand what this character really is. Can anyone help me find out?

Comment: So , you have a string  "foobar" and you want to add spaces between chars of the string ...... what do you mean "without using space"? It will be awesome if you can provide a good example with the desired output.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well according to [this](https://www.av8n.com/computer/utf/font-chart.html), `342\200\211` is a thin space in Unicode.

What do you mean by "create a space character without using space"?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a thin space. Is it ever used in a coding context?

Comment: No. It's just a fancy version of a space. Just looks - nothing to do with coding.

Answer (score 1):

The value shown by od -c is in octal. The character that is represented by those three numbers has to be searched for. Getting back the numbers from octal to hex:

```
342 200 211 = 0xE2  0x80  0x89
```

Searching for `utf8 0xE2  0x80  0x89` [this site is found](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm) which shows that the UTF-8 byte sequence `0xE2  0x80  0x89` belongs to the UNICODE code point 2009, or simply `U-02009`.
That code point is named `thin space`, which, yes, is a character similar to `U-0020`, space.
So yes, there are several characters similar to an space in UNICODE, all of them valid and all of them similar to a simple space.

I just wonder: Why are you asking?.

Comment: I found this character in my code output one day on a whim, and I couldnt' find any answers about it. It was just unintuitive that there would be such characters in existence. It caused me a good hour of fixing bugs, and it finally hit me that the  "space" I had probably wasn't a space.